# Is it possible to run AfterBuild target from csproj.user file?

Tags: msbuild, csproj, msbuild-target, csproj-user

I want to extend my local build process in `.csproj.user` file which is not tracked within our git repository. Previously I used `PostBuildEvent` but suddenly I discover that it does not work well with variables: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/677

Works from both `.csproj` and `.csproj.user` but cannot have variables:

```xml
<PostBuildEvent>xcopy "C:\workspace\project\bin\Debug\my.dll" "C:\Program\bin" /y</PostBuildEvent>
```

Works only if placed in the end of `.csproj` but not in `.csproj.user`:

```xml
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)\$(OutputPath)\my.dll" DestinationFolder="C:\Program\bin" />
</Target>
```

Also I tried to debug it with simple `<Message>` instead of `<Copy>` with same result.

Is there a way to make it work in my `.csproj.user`?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the same problem, after some experimentation the solution is quite easy:

```
<Target Name="UseAName" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)\$(OutputPath)\my.dll" DestinationFolder="C:\Program\bin" />
</Target>
```